# Replace Variables in String?

Tags: c#, string

I am Searching though the contents of a Excel Spreadsheet template at replacing all the variables represented by @Something.

I have all the variables names come up with code, i'm just looking for a way to replace the them in a string.

**Example:**

My name is @Name

**I want it to become:**

My name is John.

---

My Code explained:

I have an array holding a struct which holds:

TagPointer: this is my variable @name,
TagValue: this would be the name John

Here i can get the index of where my variable is and i have the original String its Comp.
I am just unsure how i can replace the @Something.

```
int testnum;
if (Comp != "null")
{
    if (Comp.IndexOf(ArrayNode[i].TagPointer) != -1)
    {
        testnum = Comp.IndexOf(ArrayNode[i].TagPointer);                          
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a [replace function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) you can use to replace text. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Lol Voted every one up, and i got -2, haha No worry's thanks for letting me know about the .Replace function, its what i was looking for :) +1 to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, can't you use the [string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) function?

You could do something like:

```
foreach (var tag in ArrayNode)
{
  Comp = Comp.Replace(tag.TagPointer, tag.TagValue);
}
```

Comment: Not looking to change any values in my Array, But Comp.Replace(tag.TagPointer, tag.TagValue); seems to work fine :), Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 12):

use `string.Format()`, `string.Replace()` there is less convenient

```
string value = "John";
string result = string.Format("My name is {0}", value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever seen the [`FormatWith` extension](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables.aspx)?

With it you can write something like this:

```
Status.Text = "{UserName} last logged in at {LastLoginDate}".FormatWith(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not using
ie

```
string name = "Giusepe";
string _tmp = "My name is @Name";
_tmp = _tmp.Replace("@Name", name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over your array and use the [`.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) to see which tag you have present and use the [`.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to replace the tag with the actual value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be unneccesary to do `Contains`? There is no error message or exception when `Replace` doesn't find the tag.

Comment: Thanks i have looked into the .contains() already, i just did not know about .Replace, Thank you.

Comment: @Default: I think that if one uses the `Contains` method, one would be able to call `break` to avoid doing unnecessary loops.

Comment: Speed is important to me, as i'm searching though lots of Excel Cells.

Comment: @Pommy: Then I would recommend you modify the selected answer's response and make sure that if the string contains what you are after, you then call `break`.

Comment: If i have two loops inside each other, the break will just exit the first loop?

Comment: @Pommy: The `break` statement should exit the loop within scope is running, so, `while(a){...while(b){break;}}` will break the `while(b)'. loop

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this:

```
string a = "@Something";
a = a.Replace("@somethig", Value);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Years later, we now have [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to help with this.